# How to ignore all char except the first and last occurence to do a substring?

Tags: java

I try to extract a specific content. This content is the param of `findTestObject` function. So I built this method :

**Java Code**

```
String testObjectExtracted = line.substring(line.indexOf("(") + 1, line.indexOf(")") + 1);
String testObjectPathExtracted = StringUtils.substringBetween(testObjectExtracted, "findTestObject(", ")");
testObjectPathExtracted = testObjectPathExtracted.substring(1, testObjectPathExtracted.length() - 1);

System.out.println(line);
System.out.println(testObjectExtracted);
System.out.println(testObjectPathExtracted);
```

**Example OK**

```
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Menu/span_Menu'))
findTestObject('Menu/span_Menu')
Menu/span_Menu
```

**Example KO**

```
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Menu/Test/link (AA)'))
findTestObject('Menu/Test/link (AA)
Menu/Test/link (A
// Expected result : Menu/Test/link (AA)
```

However as you can see on above examples, I'm facing an problem if there is `(` or `)` in the path because my substring is based on `(` and `)`.

Do you have any solution to solve it please ? Thank you.

Comment: Try using `lastIndexOf()` when looking for the right parentheses, `line.lastIndexOf(")")`

Comment: It solved the problem thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `lastIndexOf()` method.

```
String testObjectExtracted = line.substring(line.indexOf("(") + 1, line.lastIndexOf(")"));
String testObjectPathExtracted = testObjectExtracted.substring(testObjectExtracted.indexOf("(") + 1, testObjectExtracted.lastIndexOf(")"));
testObjectPathExtracted = testObjectPathExtracted.substring(1, testObjectPathExtracted.length() - 1);
```